# How can I pass a parameter from a dialog to a child workflow in CRM 2011 workflow designer?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The dialog prompts for a 'min score' value which the workflow needs as a parameter.  I have tried saving the parameter somewhere in the record that was selected for the dialog.  That works, but depending upon the result of one step in the workflow, it might need to clear it out again.  The condition that determines whether the clear is necessary does not seem to return the correct result, so the value gets cleared out anyway.  But rather than debugging that very clumsy method, I wonder if there is a better way to pass the parameter from the dialog to the workflow?  Is the system job record associated with the dialog available to the child workflow, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Workflows can't have parameters like Dialogs, but you could simulate the same thing. The dialogue could set some field values on the entity and then a workflow could trigger from those field values changing. It could be as simple as having a hidden "Start Workflow X" checkbox that fires a workflow when set to true. The workflow would probably need to clear that checkbox as the last step to be ready for next time.

Comment: That's what I have done, but I was hoping that there might be a nicer alternative.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a Custom workflow .
They can be used as steps in your dialog and they do accept Arguments.
for more information visit [this](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/crm-20112013-dialogs-and-custom-workflow-example/) tutorial as it is a nice walk-through for this approach.

it would be a time-taking way to do this though, but if you really need to use dialogs and pass parameters from them, you need to implement all your workflow functionality in a Custom Workflow.